# Newlines in textareas being ignored

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

Okay so here is a strange issue that is pretty common but I cannot seem to find a fix anywhere.

I am pulling data from a database TEXT field to display in a textarea for editing. But the textarea will not display blank lines.

Example:

DATABASE DATA

```
This is a line of text

this is another line of text with a line break above.
```

THIS IS WHAT SHOWS IN TEXTAREA

```
This is a line of text
this is another line of text with a line break above.
```

Does anyone know a way to make the blank line actually be represented in the actual HTML textarea.

Comment: how do you set the textarea's value? Also, I assume that you are aware of the fact that you need 2 line breaks to get an empty line?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What does the code that puts the data from the database into the HTML look like?

Comment: FYI, there's no reason t shouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/1n95rotm/

Comment: Probably new line `\n` rather than `\r\n` CRLF

Comment: I am pulling the data from a database text column. When I view the data in the database the line breaks are there. I simply load the data straight from the database into the textarea. But the extra lines don't work.

Comment: Also I see the js fiddle works but if you post that data the blank line will be removed.

Comment: add a newline character before adding the new textline, this should solve it, as another comment mentions

Comment: Adding the double spacing does not work.

Answer (score 2):

For the output, add this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.textareaOutput {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Already have that in the css. And it still ignores the whitespace.